# First character on each line ignored while processing file

Tags: python, loops, readfile

I am trying to read a text file and convert all the letters in Cyrillic into Latin. But on each line, the first character is ignored. Below is the code. Could somebody help me find a mistake please.

```py
alphabet = {'а':'a', 'б':'b', 'в':'v', 'г':'g', 'д':'d', 'е':'e', 
            'ё':'io', 'ж':'zh', 'з':'z', 'и':'i', 'й':'ii', 'к':'k', 
            'л':'l', 'м':'m', 'н':'n', 'о':'o', 'п':'p', 'р':'r', 
            'с':'s', 'т':'t', 'у':'u', 'ф':'f', 'х':'kh', 'ц':'tc', 
            'ч':'ch', 'ш':'sh', 'щ':'sh', 'ъ':'', 'ы':'y', 'ь':'', 
            'э':'e', 'ю':'u', 'я':'ya', ' ':' '}

path = "exec/onegin.txt"
f=open(path)
lines = list(f)

def changer(line):
    k = ''
    for i in line:
        if i in alphabet.keys():
            i=alphabet[i.lower()]
        k = k + i
    return k

for i in lines:
    a = changer(i)
    print(a)
```

As result I get these lines ...

```
...
Пoluzhivogo zabavlyat,
Еmu podushki popravlyat,
Пechalno podnosit lekarstvo,
...
```

Where first letters remain Cyrillic.

Comment: You did not define uppercase letters in `alphabet `

Answer (score 1):

You need to add .lower() to the if statement. It can't find the upper case characters in the dict.

```
alphabet = {'а':'a', 'б':'b', 'в':'v', 'г':'g', 'д':'d', 'е':'e', 
            'ё':'io', 'ж':'zh', 'з':'z', 'и':'i', 'й':'ii', 'к':'k', 
            'л':'l', 'м':'m', 'н':'n', 'о':'o', 'п':'p', 'р':'r', 
            'с':'s', 'т':'t', 'у':'u', 'ф':'f', 'х':'kh', 'ц':'tc', 
            'ч':'ch', 'ш':'sh', 'щ':'sh', 'ъ':'', 'ы':'y', 'ь':'', 
            'э':'e', 'ю':'u', 'я':'ya', ' ':' '}

path = "exec/onegin.txt"
f=open(path)
lines = list(f)

def changer(line):
    k = ''
    for i in line:
        if i.lower() in alphabet.keys():   # <---
            i=alphabet[i.lower()]
        k = k + i
    return k

for i in lines:
    a = changer(i)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Hi @shokan, as you don't have voting privilege yet, if you found this answer useful it would be [good practice to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you're going to use.